# "The type javax.el.ValueExpression cannot be resolved" error when extending checkbox related jsf components

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, custom-tags

I am creating JSF2 custom components and eclipse shows following error at the first line of the class.

```
The type javax.el.ValueExpression cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Error only shown when my component extends checkbox related components like `HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox` or `HtmlSelectManyCheckbox`. Other components like `HtmlSelectOneMenu` , `HtmlInputText` are ok.
I've checked project build-path and `javax.faces-2.1.14.jar` is already added to the build-path.

Comment: _javax.faces.2.x.jar_ depends on other [Java EE APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/) - in particular the Servlet, JSP and Expression Language APIs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved by adding **JBoss Runtime Library** to the classpath.

`Eclipse: [Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> Server Runtime -> JBoss Runtime]`

I have no idea why the error only occurred when extending checkbox components.